# The sound quality of slow playback using AVPlayer is not good enough even when using AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmSpectral

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

In iOS, playback rate can be changed by setting `AVPlayer.rate`.
When AVPlayback rate is set to 0.5, the playback becomes slow.

By default, the sound quality of the playback at 0.5 playback rate is terrible.
To increase the quality, you need to set `AVPlayerItem.audioTimePitchAlgorithm`.

According to the API documentation, setting `AVPlayerItem.audioTimePitchAlgorithm` to `AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmSpectral` makes the quality the highest.

The swift code is:

```
AVPlayerItem.audioTimePitchAlgorithm = AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithm.spectral // AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmSpectral
```

`AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmSpectral` increases the quality more than default quality.
But the sound quality of `AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmSpectral` is not good enough.
The sound still echoed and it is stressful to listen to it.

In Podcast App of Apple, when I set playback speed to 1/2, the playback becomes slow and the sound quality is very high, no echo at all.

I want my app to provide the same quality as the Podcast App of Apple.

Are there iOS APIs to increase sound quality much higher than `AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmSpectral`?

If not, why Apple doesn't provide it, even though they use it in their own Podcast App?

Or should I use third party library?
Are there good libraries which is free or low price and which many people use to change playback speed?

Comment: Just for completeness: The quality does not just depend on `audioTimePitchAlgorithm`, but also (a lot) on the source file, i.e. format, compression etc. To help your question you might want to provide a sample file you consider insufficient to slow down with acceptable quality. What constitutes "good enough" is, after all, quite opinion based. In general, have you tried experimenting with different quality audio files?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I thought it's good idea to increase the quality of the files I use. I've checked the file and I found it is 128kbps. Unfortunately it is the original file I have, so I can't increase the quality of the file more. Audio which is slowed down by AVPlayer sounds a little echoed, screaky, and distorted when the audio is voice. The bad quality is not noticeable when the audio is music.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've been searching and trying to learn AudioKit and Audio Unit or even considering purchasing a third party time-stretch audio processing library to fix the quality issue of slow playback for the last 3 weeks.

Now finally I found a super easy solution.

AVPlayer can slow down audio with very good quality by setting `AVPlayerItem.audioTimePitchAlgorithm` 
 to `AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithm.timeDomain` instead of `AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithm.spectral`.

The documentation says:

> `timeDomain` is a modest quality pitch algorithm that is less computationally intensive. **Suitable for voice**.

This means `spectral` is suitable for **music**. `timeDomain` is suitable for **voice**.

That's why the voice files which my app uses was echoed.

And that's why Apple's Podcasts App's slowed down audio quality is very high.
It must also uses this time domain algorithm.

And that's why AudioKit, which seems to be developed for music use, plays voice audio with bad quality.

Comment: you legend. I was trying to find a good way to make speed up voice sound good

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered the same issues with increasing/decreasing speed while maintaining some level of quality. I couldn't get it to work well using Apples API's. 
In the end I found that it's worth taking a look at this excellent 3rd party framework:

https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit

which allows you to do that and much more, in a straightforward manner. 
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! AudioKit and its website looks nice and looks easy-to-use. I wanna try to use it.

Comment: I've tried AudioKit but unfortunately AudioKit AKPlayer's slow playback quality is almost the same as AVPlayer's. And I can't find the option like AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithm in AudioKit.